# Ruby proper data structure for this implementation

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I would like to know of any data structure in Ruby that allows us to conveniently store pairs of numbers.

I would like to store pairs of numbers, like coordinates, in a list without regard to order.

So like `[(0,0), (0,1), ... (x,y)]`

If there are no data structures that will do this, what is the closest I can achieve with something else?

Thanks.

Comment: And yes, this simple question is a good question. @maximgladkov provided the simple answer, and @WindorC pointed out that custom tuple classes in Ruby are conveniently constructed using `Struct`. Let me also note that depending on what you are doing, you might want to use some published dataset classes, such as [statsample](https://github.com/clbustos/statsample).

Comment: "I would like to store […] in a list without regard to order." – Do you want to store them in a list (which is by definition ordered) or do you want to store them in something which isn't ordered (e.g. a bag or multiset)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested array, like this:

```
 array = [[0,0], [0,1], ... [x,y]]
```

Comment: @maximgladkov, you provided the simplest pragmatic answer, +1

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Struct.html) to define a `Pair` like that.

```
Pair = Struct.new(:x, :y) do
  def to_s
    "(#{x}, #{y})"
  end
end
```

Then, yon can use it as other build-in data structures. `[Pair.new(0,0), Pair.new(1,1)]`.

If you feel the way constructing `Pair` is too tedious, define a helper method `Pair`.

```
def Pair(x, y)
  Pair.new(x, y)
end
```

At last, `[Pair(0,0), Pair(1,1)]`

Comment: There is really no reason to do this. Array already works very well as a pair, with a better notation for construction, as well as `.first` and `.last` accessors for more semantic access isntead of `[0]` and `[1]`.

Comment: @meagar I just provide another approach. It's not so handy as the array way when tearing down uncomplicated tasks.

Comment: @meagar, you are wrong. Frequently, refactoring from good to great code revolves about defining these miniclasses that one feels were not worth defining when first writing the program. Ruby programmers define classes and parametrized subclasses not nearly often enough.